# How to convert pyramid type of String to array of doubles in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, string, algorithm, double

I need to read through the string given below, so that I will have arrays of doubles from this string seperated by lines, so each line will be a different array of doubles.

```
var sampleString = """
                     55
                    94 48
                   95 30 96
                 77 71 26 67
                97 13 76 38 45
              07 36 79 16 37 68
             48 07 09 18 70 26 06
           18 72 79 46 59 79 29 90
          20 76 87 11 32 07 07 49 18
        27 83 58 35 71 11 25 57 29 85
       14 64 36 96 27 11 58 56 92 18 55
     02 90 03 60 48 49 41 46 33 36 47 23
    92 50 48 02 36 59 42 79 72 20 82 77 42
  56 78 38 80 39 75 02 71 66 66 01 03 55 72
 44 25 67 84 71 67 11 61 40 57 58 89 40 56 36
85 32 25 85 57 48 84 35 47 62 17 01 01 99 89 52
06 71 28 75 94 48 37 10 23 51 06 48 53 18 74 98 15
27 02 92 23 08 71 76 84 15 52 92 63 81 10 44 10 69 93
"""
```

For example: 1st array = [55], 2nd array = [94, 48] and so on.

I know there are similar questions to this and I tried string methods like: replacingOccurances(of:with:), trimmingCharacters(in:), split(seperator:) and so on, and I tried something like this first:

```
let lineSeperatedString = sampleString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ",")

    let whiteSpaceTrimmedString = lineSeperatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "  ", with: "")

    print(whiteSpaceTrimmedString)
```

Then the output was like:

```
 55,94 48, 95 30 96, 77 71 26 67,97 13 76 38 45,07 36 79 16 37 68, 48 07 09 18 70 26 06, 18 72 79 46 59 79 29 90,20 76 87 11 32 07 07 49 18,27 83 58 35 71 11 25 57 29 85, 14 64 36 96 27 11 58 56 92 18 55, 02 90 03 60 48 49 41 46 33 36 47 23,92 50 48 02 36 59 42 79 72 20 82 77 42,56 78 38 80 39 75 02 71 66 66 01 03 55 72, 44 25 67 84 71 67 11 61 40 57 58 89 40 56 36, 85 32 25 85 57 48 84 35 47 62 17 01 01 99 89 52,06 71 28 75 94 48 37 10 23 51 06 48 53 18 74 98 15,27 02 92 23 08 71 76 84 15 52 92 63 81 10 44 10 69 93
```

Close enough :( if you ignore some whitespaces in the beginning of each part separated with a coma

Then I tried something like following so that I can convert them to Ints but then it failed and converted each number as an int itself;

```
let myUpdatedArray = whiteSpaceTrimmedString.split(separator: "\n")
    for i in myUpdatedArray {
        let temp = i.map{String($0)}
        for j in temp {
            if let myInt = Int(j) {
                print(myInt)
            }
        }

    }
```

Sorry its a bit too long but I wanted to show everything I tried, but could not figure it out on my own

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

- `components(separatedBy: .newlines)` to separate the string into
  lines,
- `map` to map the lines to the (outer) array,
- `components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)` to separate each line into
  separate numbers,
- `compactMap(Double.init)` to convert the  numbers in a line to the (inner) array of  `Double` (ignoring invalid floating point numbers).

Putting it together:

```
import Foundation

var sampleString = """
55
94 48
95 30 96
"""

let values = sampleString.components(separatedBy: .newlines).map {
    $0.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).compactMap(Double.init)
}

print(values) // [[55.0], [94.0, 48.0], [95.0, 30.0, 96.0]]
```

Comment: I did essentially the same thing using `split`: `let pyr = sampleString.split(separator: "\n").map { $0.split(separator: " ").compactMap(Double.init) }`

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I cant give +1 yet because of my reputation so I wanted to thank you here :)

Comment: @vacawama: You are right, that works as well (because `Double.init` accepts an argument of type `SubSequence`). And it does not require the Foundation framework.

Comment: @vacawama: Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @MartinR, I was on the fence about whether my answer was different enough, and decided it was worth a separate post.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that in one line using `split` to divide the string into lines, `map` to process each line, `split` again to separate each line into individual strings, and `compactMap` with `Double.init` to convert the items into `Double`s:

```
let pyramid = sampleString.split(separator: "\n").map { $0.split(separator: " ").compactMap(Double.init) }
```

This is very similar to [@MartinR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134277/1630618) except that this is pure Swift and avoids the need for the *Foundation* framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
let rows = sampleString.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
var finalArray = [[Double]]()

for row in rows {
    let array = row.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).compactMap { Double($0) }
    finalArray.append(array)
}

print(finalArray)
```

If you're using Swift 4.0 or below, replace `compactMap` with `flatMap`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I cant give +1 yet because of my reputation so I wanted to thank you here :)