# Split a String in an [[Int]]

Tags: swift

I have a `String` and want to split it into an `[[Int]]`

```
let string = "1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9" // comma and semicolon separators!
```

The result should be

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I know hot to split into an `[Int]` by using

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
var intArray = string.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Int($0) }
```

but I have no idea how to split it into `[[Int]]`

I tried

```
var intArray = string.split(separator: ";").split(separator: ",").compactMap { Int($0) }
```

This first `split` creates a `[String]`, but the second `split` doesn't work

**Solution**

A friend helped me with it, so I want to provide the solution here, too:

```
var intArray = string.split(separator: ";").map { $0.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Int($0) } }
```

Comment: Split it by semicolon separator, then split those by comma separator. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @matt I know that, but have no idea HOW to do that

Comment: Seems simple enough. Show _some_ code we can sink our teeth into and help you with. It isn't our job to write the code for you from scratch. I know how _I_ would do it, but the idea is to help with how _you_ do it. Just keep in mind that split initially gives you substrings; you need to map those to Strings in order to proceed.

Comment: But you did _not_ put `string.split(separator: ";").compactMap { Int($0) }.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Int($0) }` into your question. That is my point. Include that code; then we can help to correct it. Saying "I have no idea" is not a good Stack Overflow question. And it's false; you _do_ have an idea!

Comment: Just take it one piece at a time. Don't try to write the entire line of code all in one go (it _is_ a one-liner). Split and see what you get. Split and subsplit, and see what you get. OK, those are substrings, so map them String and see what you get. Ok, compact map to Int and you're done.

Comment: You need another `map` so that the second split is applied to each substring from the first split. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50134075/1187415 for a similar task.

Comment: In the solution edited into the post, the first (outer) `compactMap` can be changed to `map`, because its body cannot return `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one-liner you were looking for

```
import UIKit
let string = "1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9"

var intArray = string.split(separator: ";").map {$0.split(separator: ",").map {Int($0)!} }

print(intArray)
```

Alternatively, you could use the `components` method to split by semicolon, applying a `forEach` on the resulting array, in order to append the same array split by comma, on which a map has been applied to convert it from `[String]` to `[Int]`.

```
var array : [[Int]] = []

string.components(separatedBy: ";").forEach { sub in
    array.append((sub.components(separatedBy: ",")).map { Int($0)!} )
}

print(array)
```

Both will output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```